# Scala function to change an integer

Tags: scala, dictionary

Is there any function in Scala that interchanges an integer with a letter of the alphabet? For example whenever there is a '1' in a list it is interchanged with an 'a'? I have to search through a list, if I find a '1' I have to change It to 'a' ,else print list as it is. Thanks

Comment: Tell us more about the big picture.  What are you trying to accomplish?  From what you've described there's not a built-in function that will do what I think you have in mind.

Answer (score 5):

```
def alphabet(i: Int): Char = ('a' to 'z')(i - 1)
alphabet: (i: Int)Char

scala> alphabet(1)
res0: Char = a

scala> alphabet(14)
res2: Char = n

scala> alphabet(30)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 29
```

Comment: cool! in java and c* you can do (char)('a' + i), but i like this solution better.

Comment: You could do that in scala too, btw. `('a' + 5).toChar == 'f'`

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> List[Any](2,1,5,6) map { case 1 => 'a'; case x => x }
res0: List[Any] = List(2, a, 5, 6)
```

Comment: I still can't tell what exactly you're trying to do. It would help if the question included the code you've tried so far, and a concrete example of the input/output of the function you're trying to write.